# Woocommerce Product Short Code Order by Order of IDs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I would like to order the product display by the ids that are entered in [products ids=""] short code. I need it to order by the order you enter it. So... [products ids="1,2,3"] [products ids="3,1,2"] [products ids="2,3,1"] ... all list differently.

I found this piece of code that I think is close but doesn't quite work. I'm not real familiar with this method so I am not sure what is wrong.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby' );
function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args ) {
    $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');
if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) ) {
$args['orderby']  = 'post__in'; 
}

return $args;
```

I read up on post__in but not sure how it gets the ID list I entered. Is there another/better way to grab that id list and use it for the order?

Any ideas on how to get this thing to work?

Answer (score 9):

Just add order by in your shortcode like -

```
[products ids="1,2,3" orderby="post__in"]
[products ids="3,1,2" orderby="post__in"]
[products ids="2,3,1" orderby="post__in"]
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. It seemed to ignore them. It's supposed to work that way but wasn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2020.

The products shortcode can't handle this orderby

So you can create your own foreach loop:

```
foreach ($products_to_show_array as $_product_id) {
    setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] );

    // Render product template.
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```