# How to display products with shortcode in custom order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm using woocommerce shortcode to display custom products loop, e.g. `[products limit="-1" paginate="true" orderby="menu_order" columns="5" ids="85,11,1083,256,37,12,517,68,2577,104"]`. But there's a problem – they are displaying sorted by title, but I need them to be sorted in that exact order they are in shortcode. I found no such option in shortcodes docs. Is there a way to achieve it with shortcode?

Comment: try orderby="id" ?

Comment: order by id sorts by id as integers

Comment: by default the orderby is ASC but you can add additional argument order="DESC". You can read more about the args you can use here - https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found: `orderby = "post__in"`

Source: [Woocommerce Product Short Code Order by Order of IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57730112/woocommerce-product-short-code-order-by-order-of-ids)

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query_results` hook runs after the products have been queried from the database, but before they are displayed on the page. By hooking into this hook and modifying the order of the results, it is possible to display the products in the desired order.

```
//Products shortcode custom order by id
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query_results', 'bytflow_custom_products_shortcode_order', 10, 2);
function bytflow_custom_products_shortcode_order($results, $shortcode_products){
    $attributes = $shortcode_products->get_attributes();
    $order_by_arg = get_query_var('orderby');
    // Check if there are any ids specified and that user didn't change the order
    if (empty($order_by_arg) && ! empty( $attributes['ids'] ) ) {
        $ids = explode( ',', $attributes['ids'] );
        $ordered_results = array();
        foreach ($ids as $id){
            if(in_array($id, $results->ids)){
                $ordered_results[] = $id;
            }
        }
        $results->ids = $ordered_results;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

This code checks for the presence of the ids attribute in the shortcode and, if it exists, rearranges the products in the $results->ids array to match the order specified in the attribute.  [Source](https://bytflow.com/display-woocommerce-products-in-custom-order/?so)